# dexseq_count.py vs htseq-count

Tags: analysis

I have some RNA paired-end files which I have used tophat to allign

```
~/tophat-2.0.7.Linux_x86_64/./tophat -p10 --segment-length 18
--no-coverage-search --segment-mismatches 1 -G
```

then samtools

```
samtools sort -n /media//PRE_6_8_2/accepted_hits.bam
/media/PRE_6_8_2/PRE_6_8_2.sort.hg19.bam
```

and then

```
samtools view /media/PRE_6_8_2/PRE_6_8_2.sort.hg19.bam.bam
/media/PRE_6_8_2/PRE_6_8_2.sort.hg19.sam
```

then I am trying to use DEXSeq and using the

```
python2.7 /home/3.0/DEXSeq
/python_scripts/dexseq_count.py -p yes -r name -s no
/media/PRE_6_8_2/hg19/hg19_IlluminaAnnotation_genes.gtf
/media/PRE_6_8_2/PRE_6_8_2.sort.hg19.sam
/media/PRE_6_8_2//PRE_6_8_2/untreated1fb.txt
```

and gives me

```
_ambiguous 0
_empty 39845364
_lowaqual 0
_notaligned 0
```

without any reads for any exons. 0 for everything

whereas by using the htseq-count -r name -s no everything looks fine (reads in genes)...

could you please advice me how to solve it? I really need to run the DEXseq as I want reads per exon to detect splice differences.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. this is a site about programming. Your question seems more related to biostars.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure whether this is revelant to SO, at the very least you'll need to retag it so people interested in tools you use will see your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, please use the correct genome reference file/ gene annotation file (.gff file obtained by flattening .gtf file downloaded from reference genome) and you will get the count for your exons.